# How to prune tree data structure at given depth in C

Tags: c, data-structures, tree

I am trying to write this function:

```
struct treeNode *pruneTree(struct treeNode *root, int depth);
```

Which given a tree like:

```
          1           level 0
         / \
        2   3         level 1
       / \    \
      4  5     6      level 2
     / \
    7   8             level 3
```

If depth = 1 then create a tree with depth = 1 and cut everything after so the result should be:

```
          1
         / \
        2   3  // tree with depth = 1
```

I know how to write a function that prunes the leaves and I am trying to adapt it to prune at any level:

```
int isLeaf (struct treeNode * treeNode) {
    return (treeNode->left == NULL) && (treeNode->right == NULL);
}

void removeLeaves(struct treeNode * root) {
    if (root->left != NULL) {
        if (isLeaf (root->left)) {
            free(root->left);
        }
        else {
            removeLeaves(root->left);
        }
    }

    if (root->right != NULL) {
        if (isLeaf (root->right)) {
            free(root->right);
        }

        else {
            removeLeaves(root->right);
        }
    }
}
```

What is a good strategy to do this? My approach is to replace the `isLeaf` function with a `isAfterDepth` function and using a helper function that calculates the depth, but this doesn't seem efficient. What is a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: Shouldn't you `free`/`delete` the nodes first? This looks like a program that will generate memory leaks.

Comment: I modified the program to reflect this.

Comment: Another question: you only make a copy? You do not alter the given tree?

Comment: For now I am ok with altering the original tree. I have a function cloneTree which I can use to not alter the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Copying the tree

If you intend to **make a copy** of the tree that is pruned at a certain level, you can simply use recursion and at each recursive call decrease the depth parameter with one, if the depth results in `0`, you simply do no longer recursively copy the children.

```
struct treeNode *pruneTree(struct treeNode *root, int depth) { //version where the tree is copied
    if(root == NULL || depth < 0) {
        return NULL;
    } else {
        treeNode *copyRoot = (treeNode*) malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
        copyRoot->value = root->value;
        copyRoot->left = pruneTree(root->left,depth-1);
        copyRoot->right = pruneTree(root->right,depth-1);
        return copyRoot;
    }
}
```

The code works as follows: if the given `root` pointer is `NULL` or th `depth` is less than zero, `NULL` is returned, because either we call this with the child of a leaf or the depth constraint has been reached.

If that is not the case, we make a copy of the current node: we allocate a new `treeNode` object, copy the `value` of the original node (assuming this is called `value`), and perform a recursive call to copy the `left` and `right` children.

## Altering the tree

You can also alter the current tree. In that case, you better first define a function to remove a subtree and all its descendants:

```
void prune(struct treeNode * root) {
    if(root != NULL) {
        if (root->left != NULL) {
            prune(root->left);
        }
        if (root->right != NULL) {
            prune(root->right);
        }
        free(root);
    }
}
```

Now we simply need to define a method that will prune only at a certain level:

```
struct treeNode *pruneTree(struct treeNode *root, int depth) { //version where the tree is altered
    if(root != NULL) {
        if(depth <= 0) {
            prune(root->left);
            root->left = NULL;
            prune(root->right);
            root->right = NULL;
        } else {
            pruneTree(root->left,depth-1);
            pruneTree(root->right,depth-1);
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Good that you added..I didnt have enough time right now to write big answer...thanks